# What is a single word for power-to-weight ratio?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that captures the spirit of *power-to-weight ratio*, but in a mostly non-technical sense.

The spirit I refer to is something like *efficiency*, *productivity*, *bang-for-buck*, or even *return on investment*, but also perhaps *frugality* and *prudence*.

Ideally there will be both noun and adjective forms.

The connotation should be unambiguously positive ("frugal" is too close to "penny-pinching"), and also intrinsically positive, so that additional qualifiers are not needed (for example, "efficiency" must be qualified as either "high efficiency" or "low efficiency").

"Efficiency" and "prudence" together come closest, but is there a single word capturing both?

Example usage in sentences:

- "The *word* of the new camera tripod makes it attractive for professional fieldwork"
- "Environmentally conscious consumers are increasingly demanding *word* products that minimize waste without compromising performance"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think '*lightweight*' may be the best and most widely-understood word you could use. In some contexts, 'lightweight' can mean weaker - but in the context of something where being light is *advantageous*, it is in no way negative. For example, bicycles are described as "lightweight" if they are made out of light-but-strong metals or alloys.

If you wanted to make a compound adjective that clarified something is both light yet strong, you could perhaps use 'light-but-strong', or 'light-but-sturdy'. The latter would be particularly apt for a camera tripod, as 'sturdiness' would imply it remains standing.

- "The *lightweight construction* of the new camera tripod makes it attractive for professional fieldwork"
- "Environmentally conscious consumers are increasingly demanding *light-but-sturdy* products that minimize waste without compromising performance".

The Wikipedia entry for *[titanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanium)* uses the term "strength-to-weight ratio" and notes that this quality is due to its "low-density", but these are both reasonably technical terms that are unlikely to be used in everyday English, such as your examples.

Also, consider [this example](https://phys.org/news/2015-12-exceptionally-strong-lightweight-metal.html) for reference as it is a general interest article which uses "strong and lightweight" and variations of it throughout. It would seem there is no better term, at least one widely known.

Comment: It's hard to think of anything better than this. Related terms like "portable", "manoeuvreable", "convenient", "luggable" can carry a similar meaning, but all focus on light weight and easy handling.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested the adjective **top-rated**. It may be the only way to condense *bang for your buck* and still imply excellence in a wide range of parameters, such as efficiency, features, lifespan, power consumption, etc. Product ratings generally use these parameters. Cost is almost always a consideration.

> Environmentally conscious consumers are increasingly demanding
> **top-rated** products that minimize waste without compromising performance

This would be two words for a noun unless you reword to use the adjective:

> The **top ratings** earned by the new camera tripod make it attractive for
> professional fieldwork.
>
> Consistently **top-rated**, this new camera tripod will be attractive
> for professional fieldwork.

---

> To help you figure out whether an appliance is energy efficient, the
> federal government requires most appliances to display the bright
> yellow and black EngeryGuide label. Although these labels will not
> tell you which appliance is the most **efficient**, they will tell you the
> annual energy consumption and operating **cost** for each appliance so you
> can compare them yourself. The American Council for an
> Energy-Efficient Economy lists the energy performance of **top-rated**
> energy-saving appliances on its web site... [*Energy Saver$*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Energy_Saver_Tips_on_Saving_Energy_Money/UZGqiOgbNTQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=top-rated%20most%20efficient%20economical&pg=PA22&printsec=frontcover)

> There were only two important improvements in quality for room air
> conditioners that did not involve **energy efficiency**. The first was
> the **reduced weight**, declining for a standard unit from 180 pounds
> in 1957 to seventy-five pounds in 1970. The second was the transition
> from the requirement of a heavy-duty 230-volt **power source** to a
> normal 1150-volt power plug...The third was that more than half of
> units tested in 1953 lacked **thermostats** and had only one fan
> speed. *Consumer Reports* commented in 1953 that all units are "very
> **noisy**" but in 1965 that "the **top-rated** models are very **quiet**." [R. J. Gordon; *The Rise and Fall of American Growth*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Rise_and_Fall_of_American_Growth/jXGYDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=top-rated%20models%20power%20price&pg=PA362&printsec=frontcover)

> Some **top-rated** models [of binoculars] in descending price categories include...
> [P. Johnsgard; *The Birds of Nebraska*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Birds_of_Nebraska/mC1lDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=top-rated%20models%20power%20price&pg=PA19&printsec=frontcover)

> Air conditioners have become much more **efficient** over the past 15
> years. **Top-rated** models now boast efficiency levels up to 50
> percent higher than the current average. [Union of Concerned
> Scientists, et al. *Cooler Smarter*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cooler_Smarter/HCGJ6IHzSUsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=top-rated%20models%20efficiency%20price&pg=PA101&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Far too hypernymic.

Comment: Hypernymic, Yes. Too hypernymic, though? The OP requests *mostly non-technical, return on investment, bang-for buck, economical, and power-to-weight ratio.*  It should also be appropriate for a tripod. AND it should be **unambiguously positive.**

Comment: Look at some of the top-rated answers on some sites. // If I remember correctly, the last time I looked at bridge cameras, the top-rated model was the one that took the best pictures, though it didn't come high on the value-for-money or ease-of-use scales. I've CV-d OP as asking for one word to do the job of several.

Answer (score 0):

Although ***compact*** tends to suggest size rather than weight, size and weight often go hand-in-hand. So:

> **compact**
>  <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> **1.1** Having all the necessary components or features neatly fitted into a small space.
>
> <sub>‘The compact machine has many features that can benefit packagers
> of pharmaceuticals, cosmetics, and small device parts.’</sub>
>
> <sub>‘The gear-driven design also makes the unit more compact than
> other similar components.’</sub>
>
> <sub>‘They provide the right set of features in a compact form for the
> right price.’</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [Lexico —
> *compact*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/compact)</sub>

Here's what the (non-compact) *OED* has to say:

> **compact**, *adj.*<sup>1</sup>
>
> **II. 3. b.** Having the parts so arranged that the whole lies within relatively small compass, without straggling portions or members;
> nearly and tightly packed or arranged; not sprawling, scattered, or
> diffuse. ***So compact order or arrangement***.
>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>
> .

Here it is in your sentences:

> *The **compactness** of the new camera tripod makes it attractive for professional fieldwork.*
>
> *Environmentally conscious consumers are increasingly demanding **compact** products that minimize waste without compromising performance.*

Answer (score -1):

The question title about 'power-to-weight' doesn't really work with the two examples. The first seems to focus on a quality suitable for *professional fieldwork*. I was going to suggest [**ergonomic**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ergonomic) but that seems more related to ease and comfort of use, so I propose the term

> **sustainable**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> **1.1** Conserving an ecological balance by avoiding depletion of natural resources.
> *our fundamental commitment to sustainable development*

from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sustainable).

Although more applicable to a working practice or policy, it is increasingly used with *objects*.

- The **sustainability** of the new camera tripod makes it attractive for professional fieldwork
- Environmentally conscious consumers are increasingly demanding **sustainable** products that minimize waste without compromising performance"